# Sending message to a Server in java

Tags: java, android, server

I'm making an android app which needs to be able to send a piece of text to a Tower server. How do I do that in java? 
  If I can't do that in Java and can in another language, how do I connect that in android-studio

Comment: The easiest way is to use HTTPS. Search for making HTTPS requests in Android.

Comment: Is that like for sending messages to tower Servers?

Comment: what do you understand under "tower server"?

Comment: Can you use HTTPS to send a message to a Tower server?

Comment: If we have the same understanding what a "tower server" is, yes. From Whatis.com: "A tower server is a computer intended for use as a server and built in an upright cabinet that stands alone."

Comment: Yes, we have the same understanding of a tower server. Thank you for clearing that up. So can you send an HTTPS request to a tower server?

Comment: as already mentioned yes. You just need an HTTP server running on the machine.

Comment: Alright, how do you add an HTTP Server to the machine

Comment: Step1: find out which OS is installed on the server.

Comment: Alright, Thank you. The server is running windows. What's the next step?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: First you need to convert that text file to JSON format. There are bunch of frameworks and libraries that you can use such as Retrofit, Volley, OKHTTP, HTTPUrlConnection

Comment: How would the server receive a piece of text if I use HTTPS? Would it be as a file?